# Detectar Hombro Cabeza Hombro con Geometría y Python

Tags: python

Me gustaría volver a recrear un proyecto que encontré en Internet sobre detectar patrones financieros con geometría: [Proyecto](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1100&context=hmc_theses)

Estoy tratando de obtener todos los vectores para el Patrón de Cabeza y Hombros, pero no sé nada sobre Geometría. No entiendo como hacer para encontrar los vectores que menciona la imagen a continuación:

[image: Informacion]

Codigo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Q1 = (2, 20)
Q2 = (4, 25)
Q3 = (6, 20)
P1 = (1, 5)
P2 = (3, 5)
P3 = (5, 5)
P4 = (7, 5)

O_ = (P2[0] - P3[0], P2[1] - Q2[1])
OQ2 = (O_, Q2)
OP3 = (O_, P3)


X = [P1[0], Q1[0], P2[0], Q2[0], P3[0], Q3[0], P4[0]]
Y = [P1[1], Q1[1], P2[1], Q2[1], P3[1], Q3[1], P4[1]]


plt.plot(X, Y, marker='o')


coordinates = [('P1', P1[0], P1[1]), ('Q1', Q1[0], Q1[1]), ('P2', P2[0], P2[1]), ('Q2', Q2[0], Q2[1]), ('P3', P3[0], P3[1]), ('Q3', Q3[0], Q3[1]), ('P4', P4[0], P4[1])]
for x in coordinates:
    plt.annotate(x[0], (x[1], x[2]))

plt.show()
```

Respuesta:
[image: respuesta]